# Adding filenames to an array?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to add filenames of certain txt files on a watched folder to an array for further analysis. The code is as following

```
$Array = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList   

$onCreated = Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action {
    $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
    $name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
    $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
    $timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated
    Write-Host "The file '$name' at '$path'was $changeType at $timeStamp" -fore white
    $file=Get-Item $root\UNB\TMP\FACT_TEMPORAL.TXT | Rename-Item -NewName {("print-"+'{0:yyyy-MM-dd-hh_mm_ss}{1}' -f (Get-Date),".txt")} –PassThru
    $archivo=$file.Name
    Remove-Item $root\UNB\TMP\FACT_TEMPORAL.txt
    comprobar_archivo($archivo)
}
```

The function to add it to the array is:

```
function comprobar_archivo($archivo) {
    Write-Host "COMPROBANDO ARCHIVO $archivo" -fore white
    $Array.Add($archivo)
    write-host "CONTENIDO INICIAL ARRAY $Array"
    foreach ($element in $Array) {
        limpia($element)
        leeyedita($element)
        printpdf($element)
        borrar($element)
        borrar_array($element)
    }
}
```

Seems that the write-host "CONTENIDO INICIAL ARRAY $Array" is not showing anything, further more the script gets frozen, it wont execute anymore. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, or how should I pass the filenames correctly in order to work.

How do I delete a specific name from the array? I was using:

```
 $Array.Remove([String[]]$archivo)
```

But it wont work...

Comment: Where does your script get stuck? You can add a few `Write-Debug` commands and the run your script with `$DebugPreference = "Continue"` to get more info about the executed commands and values.

Comment: Also: There seems to be an `else` block without an `if`? You should also format your code properly, that will make it much easier to read and find mistakes.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the code. I didnt want to post the whole thing, just the part thats giving me problems...

Comment: try debugging your code to narrow down the issue further, then share the actual proplem

Comment: I already managed to add items, seems to work for now. The problem is to remove them. 

$Array.Remove($archivo)

It will cause the script to hang. If I use: 

$Array = $Array -notlike $archivo

Will execute but will not delete the items from the list.

Comment: Seems the problem is in the foreach section of the code.
In a test Im getting the error 

Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
At C:\Users\JuanMa\Desktop\UNB\script\prueba.ps1:12 char:13
+     foreach($element in $Array)
+             ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException